# Server connects to wifi internet but there's no wifi adapter in the config/settings (rtl8821ce)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I'm seeing a lot of "wifi connects, but no internet" questions. Mine is the opposite "there is internet, but doesn't connect" :)

Well, obviously connects somehow, since there is net. The issue is that I do not see the wifi adapter in the settings.

I've read on other posts that for this adapter (rtl8821ce) there are no official drivers so I've installed whatever I found by myself, hoping that the adapter/wifi will eventually show up in the settings.

[image: my drivers]

If it matters, the pc connected to the internet even without my additional drivers. The only issue is that the connection does not show.

[image: no wifi showing]

Using the wireless-info script, this is what I got:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Sep 2023 09:00 UTC +0000

Booted last: 10 Sep 2023 00:00 UTC +0000

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.15.0-83-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 09:30:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0573:1573 Zoran Co. Personal Media Division (Nogatech) USB Audio and HID
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:c821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter Telink Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              974848  1 8821ce
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'enp1s0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.93/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85758sec preferred_lft 85758sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"PLUSNET-QKC3MH"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'PLUSNET-QKC3MH' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate:434 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/100  Signal level=-40 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.93 metric 600 
1.0.0.3 via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.93 metric 600 
1.1.1.3 via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.93 metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.93 metric 600 
192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.93 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         757       1  0 08:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8168
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 8.051.02-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:01:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'enp1s0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8821ce
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-83-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.93/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.254, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 1.0.0.3/32, nh = 192.168.1.254, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 1.1.1.3/32, nh = 192.168.1.254, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = 192.168.1.254/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

grep: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml: Permission denied
[/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml]
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      4   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'PLUSNET-QKC3MH' [AC1]>
                    ESSID:"PLUSNET-QKC3MH"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=54/100  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'PLUSNET-QKC3MH' [AC2]>
                    ESSID:"PLUSNET-QKC3MH"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC '' [AC3]>
                    ESSID:""
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0001
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'TALKTALKE3BBBA' [AC4]>
                    ESSID:"TALKTALKE3BBBA"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'SKYW61JE' [AC5]>
                    ESSID:"SKYW61JE"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=44/100  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'SKY47Q4T' [AC6]>
                    ESSID:"SKY47Q4T"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=24/100  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'SKYW61JE' [AC7]>
                    ESSID:"SKYW61JE"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=42/100  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC '' [AC8]>
                    ESSID:""
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=51/100  Signal level=-42 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0001
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'TALKTALKE3BBBA' [AC9]>
                    ESSID:"TALKTALKE3BBBA"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=39/100  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0003
          Cell 10 - Address: <MAC '' [AC10]>
                    ESSID:""
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=45/100  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Extra:fm=0001

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-83-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-83-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/8821ce.conf]
options 8821ce rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-8821ce.conf]
blacklist rtw88_8821ce
blacklist rtw88_8821c
blacklist rtw_8821ce
blacklist rtw_8821c

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mdadm.conf]
options md_mod start_ro=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf]
alias pci:v00001186d00004300sv00001186sd00004B10bc*sc*i* r8168
alias pci:v000010ECd00002600sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8168
alias pci:v000010ECd00002502sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8168
alias pci:v000010ECd00008161sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8168
alias pci:v000010ECd00008168sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8168

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  606.497339] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  608.513326] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  608.513346] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  610.529341] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  610.529362] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  612.545349] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  612.545370] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  614.561357] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  614.561376] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  616.577362] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  616.577380] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  618.593368] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  618.593388] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  620.609371] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  620.609390] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  622.625379] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  622.625401] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  624.641382] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  624.641403] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  626.657387] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  626.657404] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  628.673392] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  628.673412] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  630.689391] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  630.689416] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  632.705399] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  632.705424] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  634.721395] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  634.721417] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  636.737395] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  636.737417] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  638.753395] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  638.753414] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  640.769397] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  640.769419] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  642.785396] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  642.785414] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  644.801395] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  644.801417] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  646.817398] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  646.817421] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  648.833434] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  648.833457] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  650.849405] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  650.849425] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  652.865392] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  652.865412] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  654.881392] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 
[  654.881418] enp1s0: pci link is down 
[  656.897386] enp1s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07 

########## wireless info END ############
```

In conclusion, is there a way for Ubuntu 22.04 to detect this card properly and display the connection and its settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your netplan file suggests that you will manually configure networking and wireless is missing entirely. You wish, however, for Network Manager to configure networking and include wireless. From the terminal, please do:

```
cd /etc/netplan
sudo rm 00-installer-config.yaml
```

Next, write a new file:

```
sudo nano 01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation, spacing, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x). Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Yes, Sir. That did the trick. Thanks a lot.